# Back to Google Talk

Tags: gmail, google-talk, google-hangouts

Starting from today the Google Hangouts panel in my Gmail tells me that I should join Google+ to use Hangouts. Is there a way to revert the plugin to the old Google Talk plugin in Gmail?

(Please note that the plugin is completely useless this way, showing me only that message, therefore I can't really use it to turn it back.)

**EDIT:** screenshot (sorry that I couldn't make it to be English)

[image: plugin spam error whatever]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

1. Click the join button
2. Click the cancel button on the next screen
3. The "Revert to old Chat" option should now be available

Answer (score 0):

From [Hangouts in Gmail - Hangouts Help](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?hl=en)

> ### Turn off Hangouts and use Google Chat
>
> You can go back to using Google Chat at any time.
>
> 1. Open Hangouts in Gmail.
> 2. Click your name.
> 3. Click Revert to old Chat.
> 4. Gmail will refresh, and you can start using Google Chat.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, here's what you need to do from that point forward if you don't know already:

1. Click on your name in the Hangouts box:
2. Click "Revert to old chat"

There you go. I tried to put in pics, but I had trouble doing it, so sorry for that.

Comment: In the original question: "Please note that the plugin is completely useless this way, showing me only that message, therefore I can't really use it to turn it back."